# mscorlib replacement & native code generation

Tags: .net, dll, cil, .net-framework-version, mscorlib

My problem is, I mainly create terminal applications (console applications) and send them to other people, run them on servers, on backup stores and more. When I create a new console app in Visual Studio it references it to mscorlib in standard.

My questions are:

- If I use Red Gates Reflector and decompile the mscorlib.dll, remove some stuff (liek networking, cryptography, certificate, remoting) and leave only the required my me (I ONLY use this, file IO, collections, XML), and compile the mscorlib.dll once more, **Can I link new/existing projects to the new mscorlib.dll**?
- When I create a app, then publish it, the app requires .Net Framework. I have heard about NGEN utility. But NGEN requires CIL code to get ready for a platform. Is there a tool that generates native code on my machine from a CIL app?

I know that  the native app will run slower, than NGENed app, maybe even slower than a CIL app. But I really need this kind of solution.

I create very advanced algorithms using (mostly) my classes. The only thing I need is input (console read, file read) and output (console write, file write). The collection classes I can implement by my self.

My scenario is: a write an app. I send it to someone with an Windows PC (Windows Server 2008 and newer). The person can run my app without having .Net Framework installed.

Comment: It strikes me as a bit odd that you develop stuff under .net and seem to expect people to be able to execute your creations without having .net installed.  Wouldn't it be more appropriate to develop a native app in this case?

Comment: OK. Forget about the native code generation. :-) All I want to do is replace mscorlib.dll with my own mscorlib.dll. Every exe in >Net (assembly) links to dlls. When You run Your app, the CLR loads Your app, loads the DLLs associated with it. How can I change the DLL from mscorlib.dll to mycorlib.dll?

Comment: I think this idea is probably illegal - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3109357/1220971). Why can't you use the .NET framework? .NET 2 comes pre-installed on Windows Server 2008 anyway.